# JMeter differences between stop test and stop test now radio boxes in Thread Group

Tags: testing, jmeter

Reading the manual I have a question:
In Thread Group, what is  the differences between "Stop Test" and "Stop Test Now" radio boxes.
I don't understand reading the jmeter guide which says:

- Stop test: Stop test (all threads) if sampler error occurs
- Stop test now: Stop test NOW (all threads) if sampler error occurs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are reading Javadocs, it would be better to read this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group

Documentation says:

- Stop Test - the entire test is stopped at the end of any current samples.
- Stop Test Now - the entire test is stopped abruptly. Any current samplers are interrupted if possible.

JMeter 2.10 javadocs will be clarified, if you read this somewhere else then please comment to tell where so that it is fixed.

Comment: Thank you, helps me a lot, i was reading this:
http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/AbstractThreadGroup.html